# Change color of glyph icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The standard glyph icons are pretty boring

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp

The following code works, **but instead of a filled in star with black, is there a way to make it some other color, e.g., orange?**

**In addition, is there a more interesting set of icons for download to use for buttons?**

```
const glyphStarEmpty = 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty';
const glyphStarFull = 'glyphicon glyphicon-star';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      currentGlyph: glyphStarEmpty 
    };
    this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this);
  }

  toggleChecked() {
    if(this.state.currentGlyph == glyphStarEmpty){
        this.setState({
        currentGlyph : glyphStarFull
        })
    }
    else{
        this.setState({
            currentGlyph : glyphStarEmpty
        })
    }

    this.setState({    
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (      
        <button className={this.state.currentGlyph} onClick={this.toggleChecked}></button>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: why can't you style it with CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline style:

```
<button style={{ color: 'orange' }} className={this.state.currentGlyph} onClick={this.toggleChecked}></button>
```

If you want a black outline in addition, try this:

```
<button style={{ color: 'orange', textShadow: '0 0 1px black' }} className={this.state.currentGlyph} onClick={this.toggleChecked}></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems natural. One question, is there a way to keep the boundary of the icon black and fill the inside with orange? I'd like more contrast.I don't mind a full black star being "unchecked" and a full orange star being checked.

Comment: Almost. there is a residual orange on the non-checked stars.I just want a plain white star with a black boundary unchecked, and a glowing orange checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple css

```
<span class="icon-some"></span>

.icon-some {
 color: orange;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the boundary of the icon black and fill the inside with orange? I'd like more contrast.

Comment: @Ivan In glyphs no, they are just like regular fonts.  Unless you do something like `text-shadow` or `text-stroke` to get a border.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, why so complicated? Just add some CSS inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .glyphicon { color: orange; }
</style>
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the boundary of the icon black and fill the inside with orange? I'd like more contrast.

Comment: not for the icons themselves, but you could use `display: inline-block;` on them and add a border with (for example) `border: 1px solid red` , then you can specify the color of that border (plus you could also add a background color, e.g. `background: #fc9;`)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a css color property like this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="orange glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.orange {color: orange;}
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the boundary of the icon black and fill the inside with orange? I'd like more contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Another icons that you can use are from [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io).They have tons of button icons and i'm sure you'll like it,i've used this icons for a lot of websites,to change the colors simply ad some css as other members told you before me

Comment: Interesting. Will look at those. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from surrounding answers, the solution became obvious. This is not perfect since I want a black border with a pure white inside (or maybe even the way stackoverflow color scheme using gray for the up/down triangles)  for unchecked state for maximum contrast, but I will fix that on my own:

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.checked)
    {
    return (      
        <button className={glyphStarFull} onClick={this.toggleChecked}></button>
      );
    }
    else
    {
       return (      
        <button style={{ color: 'orange', textShadow: '0 0 1px black' }} className={this.state.currentGlyph} onClick={this.toggleChecked}></button>
```